# Latest Javadoc for Oracle AQ / Oracle JMS

Tags: java, oracle, javadoc

I am looking for the latest JMS Javadoc of the **interface AQQueue** from Oracle.
Can anyone give me a hint where Oracle keeps the pages hidden from Google?
They must be hiding them somewhere in the basement...

I've been searching for an hour and I would need the Javadoc of Oracle 19 or newer.

And no: that: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A69464_01/nt_815/server.815/a68005/ref_java.htm#76981 is from Oracle 8...

Thanks for every hint!

Answer (score 0):

In [Oracle Database 19c bookshelf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/books.html)  I found
[Oracle® Database Advanced Queuing Java API Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajms/index.html.).

Comment: Thanks, but you won't find the AQQueue description there either

Comment: If you can only find AQQUEUE in Oracle 8 documentation on docs.oracle.com it likely means that it does not exist any more in later releases. Sorry but I cannot help more.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it definitely exists in oracle 19, but they changed ORADataFactory to OracleDataFactory in one override of the dequeue method... I just wanted to read this in the manual and not just from decompiled code.